# VirtualBox black screen after installing guest additions

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm running `lubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` in `VirtualBox` (Version 5.2.42_Ubuntu r137960).

My physical system is `Ubuntu 18.04`.

After the installation of `Lubuntu 20.04` in VirtualBox, the screen was black in fullscreen mode.
So I wanted to fix it and installed the following in guest OS (20.04):

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms`

After I restarted it, the screen is black even when not in fullscreen mode.
Can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you install the guest additions? You should mount the ISO of the additions from a guest machine menu. It is unclear what you did. Installing the additions from Ubuntu repos is wrong in most cases. It is a wrong version.

Comment: @Pilot6 ...from what i was reading, what he has there is the way to do it now.... Are you saying that ubuntu doesn't keep up with the latest versions? I've always pulled down guestadditions from the repository (which puts the iso where the guests can find it to be mounted)... But on my next install I was going to try it this way.

Comment: I mean that Guest additions version should match the VB version. If you install VB from a deb file, it makes no sense to install the Additions from Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 1):

Shut down the guest and, from VM Settings > Display, change it to the older VBoxVGA controller (the one with no S).